# How do you hide the indent arrows in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I recently opened vscode and saw this arrow showing up when I highlight indents.
I think it has something to do with the font I'm using. How do I hide it?

[image: arrow in selected indent]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

look up `whitespace` in settings; there's an option to show it all the time, only when highlighted, or never.

I believe the default annoyingly changed to 'when highlighted' in the most recent version, so you can switch it back to never.

edit as per comment below:
the exact setting is `editor.renderWhitespace`